# subprocess.check_call throws FileNotFoundError even though file exists

Tags: python, windows, permissions, subprocess, frida

I'm trying to edit the `frida-ios-dump` project to actually work for on my PC and I'm currently running into a weird issue that I think has to do with permissions somehow.

```py
chmod_dir = os.path.join(PAYLOAD_PATH, os.path.basename(dump_path))
chmod_args = ('chmod', '655', chmod_dir)
try:
    subprocess.check_call(chmod_args)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
    print(err)
```

This piece of code here throws this error: `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified` but I had a good feeling that that file DID in fact exist, so I added the following `except`:

```py
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(chmod_dir)
    print("FileNotFound, yet path exists: " + str(os.path.exists(chmod_dir)))
```

And as suspected, the file DOES exist! My code prints `FileNotFound, yet path exists: True`
and since I also printed the path, we can see that here: `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\Payload\protobuf.fid` and upon manually visiting that folder, I confirmed that the file does indeed exist there.

I have a strong feeling that this is some permission problem, but I'm not sure what I could do to fix it.

**Note:** The Python script is ran from Windows PowerShell which in turn was opened with administrator privileges.

Comment: The error is because "chmod" is not found. Windows doesn't include a chmod.exe program. You may have it as part of an MSYS2 or Cygwin installation, or maybe Git for Windows. The normal command to change file permissions in Windows is icacls.exe, but the syntax is completely different, and it works directly with native Windows ACLs, not Unix permission bits.

Comment: You can probably skip this step, unless there's some reason you need to grant other users read and execute access (5) to a file in the "Admin" user's profile directory, but grant the "Admin" user only read and write access (6) but not execute access. By default, a user has full control over files in their profile directory, and other than administrators and SYSTEM, no one else has any access.

Comment: Oh wow @ErykSun that's interesting.. I do have git for Windows installed but you may be right about being able to skip it. It's late here now so I will have to check this out tomorrow and will update once I know the results! Thanks for your comments :)